# Sampling plan for a large data set showing a given pattern

Tags: sampling, survey

I have a large set of data sets. For instance, it has 30000 data points, which are identified as $1, 2, 3,\dots, 30000$.  For notational purposes, $D(i)$ represents the data value for a point identified as $i$. These data points have the following localized pattern,
For a given integer value $k$,  $D(3k+1) < D(3k+2)$, and $D(3k+2)>D(3k+3)$, $k=1,\dots,9999$.

If I want to sample a subset of these 30000 data points for estimating the probability model for these data set, how should I choose the sample size or how to setup the sampling plan?

If the pattern is changed to $D(3k+1)< D(3k+2)< D(3k+3)$, how the sampling plan should be determined then?

Comment: Perhaps you could add a little more on why you're sampling the data that you already know the structure of.

Comment: These data points come from a force sensor. The recorded forces vary over the time horizon, and demonstrate the pattern such as what I described in the post.

Comment: sorry, missed the bit on the probability model as the purpose... so the two patterns are either alternating rising and falling or continuously increasing by an unknown amount?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: You need to state what your goal of analysis is. Sampling is used to estimate a parameter of the population or the process, such as the mean or a proportion of certain response. "A probability model" sounds too generic to describe what it is that you want to do with these data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need a sampling plan? 30,000 isn't a particularly large data set, unless there are a lot of variables for each i.

If this were me (and, if so, this would be time series data collected on equal time intervals), I wouldn't sample at all if 30,000 were too many. Instead, I'd stratify by time (say, 4 groups of 7500), simultaneously shrinking the data set and providing a replication and enabling a test for the stability of the model parameters over time. This ducks the issue of appropriate sampling in the presence of autocorrelation.

Caveat: Force sensors aren't something I'm familiar with, so it's possible that this lack of domain knowledge renders this answer faulty.

Comment: The data points can be larger. 30,000 here is just used for illustration purposes. My interest is that how to setup the sample size, which can be 1/4 or 1/8 of 30000, without losing any statistical significance. For example, I would like to be able to say something, such as we can just draw a sample for every 10 points. How to design this kind of plan is my question.  I think there should have a formal way to design this kind of plan statistically.